# Countable additivity does not imply continuity at $\emptyset$ for non-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

An exercise from Probability by Shiryaev:

Give an example to show that if a measure $\mu$ on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ takes the value $+\infty$, countable additivity ($\sigma$-additivity) in general does not imply continuity at $\emptyset$.

Here, countable additivity for $\mu$ is given by, if, for all pairwise disjoint subsets $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in\mathcal{A}$, then
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{n}).$$

Here, continuity at $\emptyset$ means that if $\{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a non-increasing sequence in the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\emptyset$, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{n})=0.$$

Comment: You can show your work/steps, for example can you define continuity at $\phi$, and can you describe the nature of the desired example?

Comment: Okay, so then, can you think of the simplest example of a measure space where some sets have infinite measure? [Simultaneously/alternatively, you might re-do the proof of continuity at $\phi$ for finite measure spaces, and see what goes wrong without finite measure.]

Comment: @Michael Could you give any suggestions that are "elementary", i.e. the book hasn't covered Borel sets and such yet.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}$? (i.e., consider the real number line)

Comment: How about $A_n=[n,n+1]$ (with, say, the Lebesgue measure) as a counterexample to your "continuity at $\emptyset$".

Comment: @HenningMakholm  I think "continuity" in this setting means the the $A_n$ are nested. But changing your $[n,n+1]$ to $[n,\infty)$ should do it.

Comment: Well, I guess there is not much left for GurrVasa to do...

Comment: @user25959: The definition provided in the question requires only that the $A_n$ are "non-increasing", which ought to mean something like $\forall n.\,A_n \not\subset A_{n+1}$.

Comment: Definition of continuity of measures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take for instance $\Omega = \Bbb Z$, $\mu$ to be counting measure, and the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ to be the power set of $\Bbb Z$. Then $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and the sets $A_n = [n,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z$ are non-increasing with $\bigcap_{n\ge 1} A_n = \emptyset$, but $\mu(A_n) = \infty$ for each $n$.